# Natural number properties as uninterpreted functions in first order logic

Tags: lo.logic, peano-arithmetic

Can we express the following property of natural numbers as FOL. The property given below is only indicative, I am more interested in knowing how the concepts such as "infinitely many X exists for so and so" can be expressed in FOL. Also these need to be expressed as uninterpreted functions.

> "For every natural number n, there are infinitely many other natural numbers such that the greatest common divisor of n and each of these other numbers is 1"

As I said if you can't express this sentence in FOL at least suggest links/material where I can get leads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f(n)$ is a predicate in the first order language of arithmetic,
then "there are infinitely many $n$ such that $f(n)$ holds" can be
expressed as
$$\forall m\in\mathbb{N}\ \exists k\in\mathbb{N}:f(m+k+1).$$

Comment: Or: For all m there is a k larger than m such that f(k).

Comment: Okay. I was a bit confused as per who the "infinitely many.." is represented. 